# How does schnorr signature construct multisig functionality?

Tags: multi-signature, schnorr-signatures, musig

- How does the multiparty schnorr signature work and enable multisig
  functionality in Bitcoin?
- What are its limitations? Can we construct any m of n signature?
- Is there anyway to hide the signers among the participants?

*I specifically would like to see the elliptic curve math in details.